# File is not able to upload in Magnolia

Tags: spring-mvc, magnolia

I have the Controller below :

```
 @Controller

 public class UploadComponent {

 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadComponent.class);

 @RequestMapping("/uploadFile")
 public String render(@ModelAttribute("fileUpload") FileUpload fileUpload, ModelMap model)throws RepositoryException {

    return "components/upload.jsp";
 }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public  String uploadFileHandler(@ModelAttribute("fileUpload") FileUpload fileUpload, HttpServletRequest request) {

    logger.info("post method executed");
    CommonsMultipartFile file = fileUpload.getPhoto();

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    ...
    ...
    }
 }
```

The Model Class as follows :

```
public class FileUpload implements Serializable {

CommonsMultipartFile photo;
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(CommonsMultipartFile photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}
}
}
```

My Jsp as follows :

```
    <form:form commandName="fileUpload" method="POST"action="uploadFile" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data">

          File to upload: <form:input type="file" path="Photo" class="pp_text" /><br /> 
          Name: <form:input type="text" path="name" class="pp_button" /><br /> <br /> 
          <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!

    </form:form>
```

I have configure the CommonsMultipartResolver in applicationContext.xml file

When I am submitting the form I am unable to getting the file.
It is not setting the "Photo" field.

So I am getting the NullPointerException in Controller while retrieving the photo field.

Can anyone suggest me Where the problem exist?

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, it is Magnolia getting in your way ... should be easy to verify. In your controller just before you get NPE, try to call `MgnlContext.getParameter("Photo")` and see what you get. Or to see whole posted form you can also do `MgnlContext.getPostedForm()`.
If you verify that it is indeed Magnolia that holds the value of the field, you can either forget about processing field yourself and let Magnolia handle multipart for you or if that is not what you want, you can configure bypass for `MultipartFilter` in `config:/server/filters/multipartRequest` to tell Magnolia to not touch anything that is coming in for your controller uri.

If that the above doesn't help, you can try to add `info.magnolia.debug.DumpHeadersFilter` in the filter chain (anywhere after context filter) and see in the log what it tells you about incoming request. Despite the name, it will also print out params and values. Maybe that can give you some clue.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Hi @Jan, I thinks I am getting something. While I am performing  **MgnlContext.getPostedForm().getDocument("file").getFile()**  I am getting the output as : **E:\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\myproject-webapp\tmp\ico1.png** , While I am performing **MgnlContext.getParameter("file")**  I am getting **NULL** . Can you please clarify this scenario ? Why I am getting ?

Comment: Ooops. My bad. I should have read the javadoc properly. It does say "Get a parameter value as string." so I presume if it can't return string, which for file it can't, it will respond w/ null instead. Glad that at least the other way worked for you. https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/5.3.7/apidocs/info/magnolia/context/WebContext.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using *Magnolia Blossom* it comes with its own multipart resolver that, it seems, transparently wraps around Magnolia's multipart filter so that you don't have to bypass the latter or use a workaround to get to the uploaded file.

Replacing my CommonsMultipartResolver bean with info.magnolia.module.blossom.multipart.**BlossomMultipartResolver** (as described [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS45/Blossom+module#Blossommodule-MultipartRequests)) solved my very similar issue where my MultipartFile field was always null in the uploaded form.

Comment: This was the perfect fix.